# I want to get on those users their meta value are like "AGENT" .. but this query is not working

Tags: query, mysql, sql

```
SELECT display_name FROM $wpdb->users WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id from $wpdb->usermeta where meta_value LIKE '%agent%')
```

Comment: How are you running that query - in WordPress, where the $wpdb-> would make sense, or directly in mysql? When you say 'is not working' do you get an error, or no results, or something else?

Comment: And you want to look for 'agent' in any meta value, not just one specific meta key? Can you show us an example user's usermeta that you're trying to find?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT display_name FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."users WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id from ".$wpdb->prefix."usermeta where meta_value LIKE '%agent%')";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Comment: So you've just changed $wpdb->users to explicitly append the prefix to "users"? I don't think that makes any difference.

Comment: He haven't added the table prefix to the table names then how would it work without it ? Let's see if it works for him.

Comment: $wpdb->users is already the table name including the prefix

Comment: Please refer to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566072/wpdb-table-name

Comment: That example doesn't work because it's not a standard WordPress table so there isn't a property for it in wpdb. The user table is a standard table so $wpdb->users works fine.